# programatically adding and removing events from a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've got a GridView like below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Results" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="Results_RowDataBound">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>No results found</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>



Protected Sub Results_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
            'do a bunch of work here
End Sub
```

Based upon user input, sometimes I want the OnRowDataBound event to fire, sometimes I don't.

Is there a way to programatically turn the event on or off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample code to [add and remove events in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(VS.80).aspx) programatically :

```
If CheckBox1.Checked Then
    AddHandler Results.RowDataBound, AddressOf Results_RowDataBound
Else
    RemoveHandler Results.RowDataBound, AddressOf Results_RowDataBound
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier to add an if inside your event handler and ignore the event when you don't need it?