# Adding Events to Dynamically created GridView controls in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

What I want is do add events to my dynamically created GridView controls in VB.NET.  Here is my code.

```
Dim dgData as New GridView()
dgData.RowDataBound += New GridViewRowEvendHandler(dgData_RowDataBound)
```

Every time I right the code above I get the blue squiggle line under dgData.RowDataBound and here is the reason:

`"Public Event RowDataBound(etc...)`is an event, and cannot be called directly.  Use a `'RaiseEvent'` statement to raise an event"

How can I get rid of the blue squiggle line so I can add my new event handler to this RowDataBound?

Answer (score 3):

Could this be what your looking for?
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/687293/614263

You need to review Events in VB.  It looks like your trying to use C# syntax there.